# Access DB from C# using System.Data.Entity but NOT EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

My company has an older ASP site that looks like it's written using model-first EF pattern... Except there are no references to EntityFramework.dll anywhere.  Talking to the original coder, it doesn't seem he actually knows how he got it to work.  He though EF was in the System.Data.Entity namespace as it comes in the framework.

How is it that he was accessing a database (DB2) using models/entities but not actually referencing the EF anywhere ?

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: No Linq-to-Sql in here.  The only things used other than the standard framework is the Enterprise Library.  And maybe that has it in there... I've just never used it before.

Comment: I can't post the code... There's so much of it and I'm pretty sure they would have issue with that (IP and all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that EF 4 was initially released as part of .NET 4.0.  Only since EF 4.1 was it separated into its own package.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation from [MSDN for `System.Data.Entity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity(v=vs.113).aspx):

> The System.Data.Entity namespace contains classes that provides access
>   to the core functionality of the entity framework.

To access a database without Entity Framework, you can use [ado.net](/questions/tagged/ado.net). It is the first level of data access and you should learn it before using any ORM tool. Check the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` to have types to access Sql Server database. If you check each type, you will see there is a common convention to implement a ado.net data access in .Net. WE have `DbConnection`, `DbCommand`, `DbTransaciton`, `IDataReader`, etc. All these common types you can see in `System.Data.Common`.

For the `DB2` database, you can download the .Net Provider for data access with Db2 in [this link](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html) because it is not native provider. It is the same way as you do for other database, but use the specific .Net Provider.